# mail() function only sending email to one of the 2 gmail accounts i own

Tags: php

i am getting a very peculiar type of problem with the mail() function.

I am testing my script with 2 of my Google email accounts. i successfully receive email on one of the Google mail accounts but not to the other.

This is the code:

```
$to = "emailone@gmail.com" ;
$subject = "This is an email sent from my script." ;
$message = "well done sunny Jim";

mail($to,$subject,$message);
```

I have also checked the spam folder:D.

Comment: Gmail does not deliver e-mails that have the same From and To address. Make sure that's not your case.

Comment: Did you check your spam box?

Comment: @Mike Yes, he checked.

Comment: @OndřejMirtes: That’s not true (at least not in general, have done the very same thing successfully often enough).

Comment: Check `mail` function with `if`.Maybe you have error.Or check `logs` file.

Comment: You tested in `localhost`???

Comment: thnx for the replies. I am running the script from my hosting account.